# Singular value decomposition of a $3\times 1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I want to calculate the singular value decomposition $U\Sigma V^T=A$ with $3 \times 1$ matrix $A=(1, 0,  -1)$. I know that, in order to get the $3 \times 1$ matrix $\Sigma$ I have to calculate $B=A^TA$ which has $B=(2)$ as a result, meaning that $\Sigma=(\sqrt2, 0, 0)$. Now I have to calculate the determinant of $B-\lambda$ to get the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,..,n}$ and the eigenvectors of $B$ in the next step. But here's my problem: I can't figure out how to do this with just a single number instead of a matrix. It would be great if someone could show me how it is done.

Comment: Singular value decomposition takes a rectangular matrix. What is the meaning of decomposing a vector ?

Comment: It's a task I found in the collection of exercises for my linear algebra course and I just don't know how to handle it. I'm also a little bit confused about the task itself.

Comment: Hint: $\det 2=2$.

Comment: See [does-it-make-sense-to-talk-about-eigenvalues-in-a-1x1-matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067507/does-it-make-sense-to-talk-about-eigenvalues-in-a-1x1-matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of SVD we look for orthogonal matrix $U$ of dimension $3\times3$, a matrix $\Sigma$ of dimensions $3\times1$which is actually a column vector, already found by the author of the question: $\Sigma=(\sqrt2,0,0)^T$ and a $1\times1$ matrix $V$ which is a scalar that we take to be $1$ (since it should be an "orthogonal" matrix made of unit vectors). Now solving $U\Sigma V^T=A$ for the elements of $U$ we just get information for the 1st column of $U$ which is: $u_{11}= 1/\sqrt2$, $u_{12}=0$, $u_{13}=-1/\sqrt2$. The other 2 columns of $U$ are found by imposing the orthogonality conditions with unit vectors and we easily find:
$ 
U=\begin{bmatrix}
    1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
       -1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$